# How to integrate with respect to $x^2$?

Tags: calculus

$$\int x\,dx^2$$

I'm having trouble comprehending this question. I can perform substitution, but when I do I come out wrong. Here's how I've happened to handle this:

$\int x\,dx^2$

$u=x^2$

$du=2x\,dx$

$dx=\frac {du}{2x}$

$\frac12 \int x\frac{du}{2x}$

$\frac 12\int\frac12\,du$

$\frac u4$

$\frac {x^2}{4}$

It says that it's wrong. Me showing my work was just a desperate attempt at solving it. I'd really like a guide through the problem please.

Also, apparently the answer is $\frac {2x^3}{3}$

Comment: You substituted $\mathrm{d}x$ for $\mathrm{d}(x^2)$, but these are not equal.

Comment: So would that apply to my $du$? Thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: My Russian high school teacher always said "Back in Russia it was minus $50$ points for forgetting the $+C$." For us, it was minus $10$ points the first time, but minus all the points any subsequent times. I learned after the first time. In short, the answer should have a $+C$.

Comment: Indeed.  These [[1](http://spikedmath.com/434.html)] [[2](http://spikedmath.com/508.html)] comics should make you laugh and remember to be in the habit of keeping those +C's (or +monkeys etc...) to avoid losing points.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt: glad that such teachers don't live here in Russia :) Forgetting $+C$ seems to me like a typo, if the concept of "$+C$" is understood :)

Comment: Oh boy, I didn't realize that I left it out. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $u = x^2$, then modulo a sign, $x = \sqrt{u}$. Hence the integral is equal to

$$\int \sqrt{u} \ du = \frac{2}{3}u^{3/2}  \ (+ C) = \frac{2}{3}x^3 \ (+ C)$$

Answer (score 4):

An alternative approach: $d(x^2) = 2x\,dx$ so you have

$$\int x\,d(x^2) = \int 2x^2 \,dx = \frac{2}{3}x^3+C.$$

Answer (score 2):

Everything was going fine until $$\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{2x}$$. Instead, letting $u=x^2\implies x=\sqrt{u}$
$$\int\!x\,\mathrm{d}(x^2)=\int\!\sqrt{u}\,\mathrm{d}u$$
$$=\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{u}^3+c$$
$$=\frac{2}{3}x^3+c$$

Comment: I see what I did! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

you can solve this integration by another method.
As we are familiar with integrating with dx instead of $dx^2$, so it will be easier if we translate it to an integral with dx.

Let $y = \int x\,dx^2$
so $\frac{dy}{dx^2}=x$ then we divide by $dx$
to get $\frac{\frac{dy}{dx}}{\frac{dx^2}{dx}} = x$.
$\frac{dx^2}{dx}=2x$, that mean $\frac{y'}{2x}=x$ so $\frac{dy}{dx}=2x^2$ so $y = \frac{2x^3}{3}+k$

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple:

$$\int xdx^2 = \int \sqrt{x^2}dx^2=\frac{2}{3}x^3 + c$$