# Indefinite double integral of a single variable function.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Can an indefinite double integral of a single variable be defined? The idea is basically integrating the result of the indefinite integral to the same variable.

$$ \int \left(\int f(x)dx \right)dx $$
Edit: Forgot to ask it at first, would the following be a correct for it as well?
$$\iint f(x) dx^2 $$

Comment: Yes, it can: like the relation between acceleration ($a$), and position ($x$) in physics, where $\displaystyle a(t)=\int \int x(t) dt$

Comment: @Mehrdad You surely mean $x(t)=\iint a(t)dtdt$. However, in the contest of differential forms, wouldn't this integral be zero?

Comment: Yeah I meant what you said thank you. Btw, why would  this integral be zero? @Messney

Answer (score 0):

The expression $\displaystyle \int f(x) \, dx$ is typically understood to mean "a general antiderivative of $f$". Any two such antiderivatives (on an interval) only differ by a constant.

It would be entirely consistent for your notation to be read as "a general antiderivative of a general antiderivative of $f$". As such, you could write

$$\int \left( \int x^2 \, dx \right) \, dx = \int \frac {x^3}{3} + C \, dx = \frac{x^4}{12} + Cx + D.$$

This (in my experience) is highly nonstandard, however.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it can. For an easy example, take any function $g(x)$ whose second derivative $g''(x)$ exists.

Then we have $$\int \left(\int g''(x) dx\right)dx $$
$$ = \int (g'(x)+c_1) dx$$
$$ = g(x) +c_1x+c_2$$

For constants $c_1$ and $c_2$

---

For your second question, I am not personally familiar with the notation of $dx^2$ but it appears to be used for solving problems such as [How to integrate with respect to $x^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1288831/how-to-integrate-with-respect-to-x2)