# Integration of $(x)d(x^2)$, is my solution mathematically correct?

Tags: integration

Just for my own understanding of how exactly integration works, are these steps correct:

$$\begin{align}\int x\,d(x^2) \qquad &\implies x^2 = u \\ & \implies x= \sqrt{u}\end{align}$$

Thus, it becomes $$\int\sqrt{u}\,du = \frac{2}{3}u^{3/2} \implies {2\over3}x^3$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While fundamentally correct, aside from your lack of a $+C$ constant, notationally your work is a bit of a mess (before someone edited it for clarity's sake).

First, we start with

$$\int x d(x^2)$$

From here, we make the substitution $u = x^2$. This gives $x = \sqrt{u}$. Thus,

$$x d(x^2) = \sqrt{u} du \;\;\; \Rightarrow \;\;\; \int xd(x^2) = \int u^{1/2}du = \frac{2}{3}u^{3/2} + C$$

Reutilizing our substitution, we finally get our answer:

$$\frac{2}{3}u^{3/2} + C = \frac{2}{3}x^3 +C$$

Your errors make it hard to follow your thought process, because $\sqrt{u} du \neq \frac{2}{3}u^{3/2}$, when you assert they're equal in your last line.

As a note, this question was asked before: you might want to check more thoroughly next time. [The original question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1288831/how-to-integrate-with-respect-to-x2)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, except for an integration on the LHS of the last line. Also make sure to keep track of your limits. You would get the same expression when you use $d(x^2) = 2x dx$